# I can't open scrapy shell in terminal

Tags: python, scrapy

I installed scrapy with

```
pip install scrapy
```

and it was installed successfully, I can import it in my script and it works. 
However, when I use `scrapy shell "https://www.google.com"` on Windows CMD with Python3  it gives me the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

So I tried

```
pip install win32api
```

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32api
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for win32api

How can I fix this error and use `scrapy`'s shell?

Note: I'm using Windows 10 and python 3.7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install `pywin32`:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Answer (score 3):

You need pywin32 installed because of this [Twisted bug](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3707).

Install it with

```
pip install pypiwin32
```